# I need sample files for vidio-player testing

Tags: video

I searched for a video-player, which could be used in Laravel 8/jquery 3.6 app, supporting formats :
MOV, .MPEG-1, .MPEG-2, .MPEG4, .MP4, .MPG, .AVI, .WMV, .MPEGPS, .FLV, 3GPP, WebM, DNxHR, ProRes, CineForm, HEVC (h265)
I found and installed video-js(8.3.0), which seems quite good for me, but where can I get video files of
MOV, .MPEG-1, .MPEG-2, .MPEG4, .MP4, .MPG, .AVI, .WMV, .MPEGPS, .FLV, 3GPP, WebM, DNxHR, ProRes, CineForm, HEVC (h265) type for testing ?
Are there some apps in Kubunbtu 20.04 for generating/checking properties of such files ?
Some online sites/tools for this?

Comment: why do you need some like because the browser can play all that stuff natively and look at ffmpeg